# Stripe Connected Account

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a stripe connected account.

Is it possible to charge the Stripe connected Account with another Stripe Connected Account?

I am using Stripe Connected Custom not the Standard or Express

My Application is more on financing, Lender and Borrower Model.

Sincerely yours,

Pong

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. If you're using custom Connect, then destination Charges are the recommended way of creating Payments. i.e. the Platform creates the charge.